# Program with istream_iterator is crashing down

Tags: c++

Why my program is crashing down:

```
#ifndef StreamBuffer_h
#define StreamBuffer_h

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

enum StreamBufferState
{
  STREAMBUFFER_OK = 0,
  STREAMBUFFER_EOF = 1
};

// gzip plik
// type plik | gzip -d
// gzip -d plik.gz
// gzip -dc plik.gz 

class StreamBuffer
{
    istream_iterator<char> iter;
    int maxBufferSize;
    std::string buffer;
 public:
    StreamBuffer(int maxBuffSize, bool streamInput, std::string filename="")
    {
    SetMaxBufferSize(maxBuffSize);
        if(streamInput) // Wejscie strumieniowe
            iter = istream_iterator<char>(std::cin);
        else // Wejscie plikowe
            iter = istream_iterator<char>(fstream(filename.c_str()));
    }
    ~StreamBuffer()
    {
    }
    void SetMaxBufferSize(unsigned int maxBuffSize)
    {
    maxBufferSize = maxBuffSize;
    }
    StreamBufferState FullBufferWithData()
    {
        char c;
        istream_iterator<char> iend;
        for(int i=0;i<maxBufferSize;++i)
        {
            if(iter==iend)
                return STREAMBUFFER_EOF;
            c << *iter;
            buffer += c; // !!!!!! In this line program is crashing down
            iter++;
        }

        return STREAMBUFFER_EOF;
    }
    std::string GetDataBuffer()
    {
    return buffer;
    }
};

#endif
```

> Error: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'c' is being used without being initialized.

Line with error:

```
buffer += c; // !!!!!! In this line program is crashing down
```

[EDIT]
After improving my code I have:

```
#ifndef StreamBuffer_h
#define StreamBuffer_h

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

enum StreamBufferState
{
  STREAMBUFFER_OK = 0,
  STREAMBUFFER_EOF = 1
};

// gzip plik
// type plik | gzip -d
// gzip -d plik.gz
// gzip -dc plik.gz 

class StreamBuffer
{
    fstream file;
    istream_iterator<char> iter;
    int maxBufferSize;
    std::string buffer;
 public:
    StreamBuffer(int maxBuffSize, bool streamInput, std::string filename="")
    {
    SetMaxBufferSize(maxBuffSize);
        if(streamInput) // Wejscie strumieniowe
            iter = istream_iterator<char>(std::cin);
        else // Wejscie plikowe
        {
            file.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in);
            iter = istream_iterator<char>(file);
        }
    }
    ~StreamBuffer()
    {
        file.close();
    }
    void SetMaxBufferSize(unsigned int maxBuffSize)
    {
    maxBufferSize = maxBuffSize;
    }
  StreamBufferState FullBufferWithData()
    {
        char c;
        istream_iterator<char> iend;
        for(int i=0;i<maxBufferSize;++i)
        {
            if(iter==iend)
                return STREAMBUFFER_EOF;
            c = *iter;
            buffer += c;
            iter++;
        }

        return STREAMBUFFER_EOF;
    }
    std::string GetDataBuffer()
    {
        string buf = buffer;
        buffer.clear();
        return buf;
    }
};

#endif
```

I have another problem: when I read chars with stream iterators, new lines (and spaces) are ignored, why?

Comment: Why would you do a binary shift on a char ?

Comment: You should read [this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about how to debug small programs such as yours.

Comment: istream_iterator after dereference and assign it to c variable gives garbage, but I don't know why.

Comment: `c << *iter` should be `c = *iter`.

Comment: The line `c << *iter;` does not do what you think it does. `char` has no overload for `operator <<`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: After use your solution it works.

Comment: One wonders that the role of the `istream_iterator` here is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to go on, but...

You're creating an `istream_iterator` using a temporary (the
`fstream`), which will be destructed at the end of the full
expression, leaving `iter` with a dangling reference.

And of course, you never initialize `c` (which is undefined
behavior), but I suspect that this is not really why you're
crashing.  And what do you thing `c << *iter` does?  (What it
actually does is try to extract a character from the destructed
stream, then shifts the undefined value in `c` to the
left---undefined behavior if the value of `*iter` is greater
than the number of bits in an `int`---, and finally throws out
the results of the shift.)

If I'm guessing what you're trying to do correctly, the
idiomatic way of doing it would be something like:

```
class StreamBuffer
{
    std::filebuf myFile;
    std::istream myIStream;
    std::string  myBuffer;
    int myMaxBufferSize;
public:
    StreamBuffer(int maxBufferSize, std::string const& filename )
        : myIStream( filename.empty() ? std::cin.rdbuf() : &myFile )
        , myMaxBufferSize( maxBufferSize )
    {
        if ( ! filename.empty() ) {
            myFile.open( filename.c_str() );
            if ( ! myFile.is_open() ) {
                //  throw ?
            }
        }
    }
    StreamBufferState FillBufferWithData()
    {
        char c;
        while ( myBuffer.size() < myMaxBufferSize && myIStream >> c ) {
            myBuffer += c;
        }
        return myIStream ? STREAMBUFFER_OK : STREAMBUFFER_EOF;
    }
};
```

Except that I really doubt that this is what you want either: it
treats any error as end of file, it reports end of file when you
partially fill the buffer, and most importantly, it (like an
`istream_iterator<char>`) skips white space.

If you can specify exactly what you are trying to do, maybe we
could help more.

Comment: Ok, but even if I make fstream member of this class and I use fstream::open I have the same error in the same place.

Comment: Your code makes many compilation errors, first is:  error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'std::filebuf' to 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *'

Comment: @CppMonster There was a small typo, which I fixed.  (I use code similar to this daily.)

Comment: Ok, maybe I have still errors, cause I have to work in VS2008, though it thanks I managed on my own and code is similar. I still use istream_iterator.